# Letter condition in MIPS

Tags: mips, conditional-statements

What should I write as a condition to compare what I wrote from my keyboard with K?
I want my code to continue when I press the letter K.
That's my code.

```
   K1:li $v0, 4          
   la $a0, gram  #message to get the letter     
   syscall  
   li $v0,5
   syscall
   move $t4,$v0   

   bne $t4,48h,K1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should load the letter k into a register for comparison.

MIPS assembly supports character literals so you could do:

```
li $t5 'k'
bne $t4 $t5 K1
```

Comment: I figure it out.I replaced the system call 5 with system call 12 which is to read characters and then compare them.  

    K1:li $v0, 4          
    la $a0, gram        
     syscall  
    li $v0,12
     syscall
        move $t4,$v0   

      bne $t4,75,K1  
Compare is done to Dec,cause 'K' is 75.

Answer (score -2):

Ascii code for `'K'` is 4B, so you should compare the register where input byte is stored with 4Bh and then proceed if it's equal.

So assuming register `$t4` has the input code of the input byte your condition should be:

```
bne $t4,4Bh,K1
```

Also, you might consider providing additional information what some lines and functions mean when you post some architecture specific code/languague.

Comment: Syntax error means the compiler doesn't understand what you wanted to say, meaning you used some invalid syntax. Has nothing to do with logic. Check the compiler syntax for function. Maybe `cmp $t4, 4bh` `bne K1`

Comment: `cmp $t4, 4bh` compares value in register `$t4` with the value `4b` hex. If it's equal Zero flag of PSW is set, and `bne K1` will check that flag. If it's not set (not equal) it will branch to K1, if it's set (equal) it will continue.
I don't know if it's the right syntax, you have to check that. 
What compiler do you use, what's the target processor?

Comment: I should write them in different lines?

Comment: Yes, each instruction in a different line.

Comment: This answer doesn't appear to be mips assembly